# Cordova CORS call not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, rest, cors

I don't understand why, but my CORS call is not working.

I added the meta tag to index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

my android manifest has:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

the headers of my call are :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
```

In my config.xml i have

```
 <access origin="*" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

and my code is

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open("GET", "http://XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXX", true);
console.log("test");
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
   console.log("DOES NOT COME HERE?")
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
            alert(code);
            var product = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            alert(product.CNK);
        }
    }
```

"DOES NOT COME HERE" doesn't get printed, also no error printed in the log? I really don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: I think this has something to do with the fact that codova loads your index.html via file:/// protocol instead of http. I think you won't even need CORS because of that. Did you set `<access origin="*" />` in your app? You will have to whitelist the domain of the server which you want to call: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: What android version are you using? With android <4.4 CSP are ignored and with >=4.4 when there are CSP problems, the logs are explain quite much the issue. Are you building with phonegap build or locally (if building locally, I don't think just adding the plugin in config.xml is enough,it should be added with CLI). You can check if the whitelist plugin is actually present in platforms/androidassets/www/plugins folder.

Comment: I'm using KitKat, The whitelist plugin is present in platforms/androidassets/www/plugins

Comment: Did you try adding content-src: *? The content scheme is used for Ajax calls.

Comment: @RaymondCamden where should i do this? if i add this in config.xml it gives me an error that * is not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the solution was so stupid, I searched way to long for this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXX", true);
console.log("test");
request.send()
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
console.log("DOES NOT COME HERE?")
if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
        alert(code);
        var product = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        alert(product.CNK);
    }
}
```

As you see I added request.send() :)