# Cordova / Android app, $.getJSON request isn't working

Tags: android, cordova, cors

This is driving me up the wall! For some reason *JSConsole.com* isn't working for debugging, so its proving a real PITA to debug. I am using *PhoneGap Build* to create my app (a WebView app). This all worked fine before - but for some reason its stopped working. We moved over to an **Nginx** server a while back - and it looks like the CORS stuff wasn't setup right. However, I've got it returning the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    
GET, POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type    
application/json
Date    
Tue, 09 Feb 2016 15:30:32 GMT
Server  
nginx/1.9.5
X-Firefox-Spdy  
h2
access-control-allow-cred...    
true
access-control-allow-head...    
DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Ty
pe
access-control-allow-orig...    
*
```

...but it still doesn't work.

```
alert("before grab");

$.getJSON('https://exmple.net/cgi-bin/daily.cgi', { action: 'cat-list', u: device_id, t: device_type }, function(result) {

    alert("in here 1");
});
```

The first alert comes up fine in the app, but the 2nd one does not (which leads me to think that the CORS stuff isn't working for some reason).

Are there any known issues with Cordova and CORS? I'm 100% sure it used to work - but I'm unsure if its the server move that has caused this issue, or the upgrade to a later Cordova.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Just to confirm its not requesting daily.cgi, I added some debugging into it (so that it writes a log on the server when requested). As expected, it works fine when called from a browser - but not when called from the Android app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, I knew this would happen as soon as I wrote up and posted my question! I just happened to come across this page while doing more research:

[Cordova CORS call not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506378/cordova-cors-call-not-working)

In the past version, I just had this in the **config.xml**:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

However, it seems that the cordova-plugin-whitelist is now needed as well! So I added this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

...rebuilt it, and it works now! I can't believe I've just wasted 3 hours of my life fixing that up. Eugh

Comment: @CobusKruger - because I forgot about it ;) Have accepted it now.